# How to invert the output of OpenGL code?

Tags: opengl, graphics

I have written the following code to print the Koch curve using OpenGL. But I am getting an inverted output. What modifications are required to invert the output in OpenGL? Also, is there any other formula to find the vertex coordinates of the equilateral triangle of the Koch curve?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<GL/glut.h>
#define COS 0.5
#define SIN 0.866
int x1=10,x2=550,y1=200,y2=200;

void myinit()
{
    glClearColor(0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0);
    glColor3f(0.0,0.0,1.0);
    glPointSize(3.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0,640,0,480);
}

void koch(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int m)
{
        int x[5],y[5],xx,yy,lx,ly;
        lx=(x2-x1)/3;
        ly=(y2-y1)/3;
        x[0]=x1;
        y[0]=y1;
        x[4]=x2;
        y[4]=y2;
        x[1]=x[0]+lx;
        y[1]=y[0]+ly;
        x[3]=x[0]+2*lx;
        y[3]=y[0]+2*ly;
        xx=x[3]-x[1];
        yy=y[3]-y[1];
        x[2]=xx*(COS)+yy*(SIN);
        y[2]=-xx*(SIN)+yy*(COS);
        x[2]=x[1]+x[2];
        y[2]=y[1]+y[2];

        if(m>0)
        {
            koch(x[0],y[0],x[1],y[1],m-1);
            koch(x[1],y[1],x[2],y[2],m-1);
            koch(x[2],y[2],x[3],y[3],m-1);
            koch(x[3],y[3],x[4],y[4],m-1);
        }
        else
        {
            glBegin(GL_LINES);
                glVertex2d(x[0],y[0]);
                glVertex2d(x[1],y[1]);
            glEnd();
            glBegin(GL_LINES);
                glVertex2d(x[1],y[1]);
                glVertex2d(x[2],y[2]);
            glEnd();
            glBegin(GL_LINES);
                glVertex2d(x[2],y[2]);
                glVertex2d(x[3],y[3]);
            glEnd();
            glBegin(GL_LINES);
                glVertex2d(x[3],y[3]);
                glVertex2d(x[4],y[4]);
            glEnd();    
        }
}

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        koch(x1,y1,x2,y2,2);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();  
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(640,480);
    glutInitWindowPosition(10,10);
    glutCreateWindow("Grllp");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    myinit();
    glutMainLoop(); 
}
```

Comment: Inverted how? Maybe just negate the y-coordinates?

Comment: Thaks Nico, i changed the sequence of the arguments of "gluOrtho2D" function to (0,640,480,0) and the output was inverted.

Comment: @NirajWagh: Did this fix all of your questions? In this case you could  answer the question yourself.